# Persist test data across testmethods

Tags: apex

In one of my test classes, I want an opportunity to persist across all the testmethods.  how do I do that? Also, is that a best practice when it comes to apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not persist values across testmethods and is bad practice to do so. SFDC rolls back all updates at the conclusion of a testmethod

Instead, if you need an Opportunity in each testmethod, consider loading it with the Apex statement using a common-to-all testmethods mockEnv() method which you can query for in each testmethod and use as needed

```
private static void mockEnv() {
  Test.loadData(Opportunity.sObjectType,staticResourceTestDatasetName); // a csv file 
}
```

Comment: @nivyaj ...or sometimes it is useful to set the data up in a class so multiple created objects can be referenced and methods such as asserts that check several things can be written and then all this can be shared between tests - see [Cleaner inner class test fixture pattern](http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/cleaner-inner-class-test-fixture-pattern/).